# The transaction was rolled back on failover however commit may have been successful

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

I have an application using jms that sends data to an ActiveMQ Artemis queue.  I got an exception with this message:

> The transaction was rolled back on failover however commit may have been successful

This exception is basically telling me that the message may or may not have reached the queue so I don't know if I need to send the message again.  Whats the best way to handle an exception like this when:

1. I cannot send duplicate messages to applications on the other end of the queue.

and

2. I cannot skip a message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't state it better than the [ActiveMQ Artemis documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/duplicate-detection.html):

> When sending messages from a client to a server, or indeed from a server to another server, if the target server or connection fails sometime after sending the message, but before the sender receives a response that the send (or commit) was processed successfully then the sender cannot know for sure if the message was sent successfully to the address.
>
> If the target server or connection failed after the send was received and processed but before the response was sent back then the message will have been sent to the address successfully, but if the target server or connection failed before the send was received and finished processing then it will not have been sent to the address successfully. From the senders point of view it's not possible to distinguish these two cases.
>
> When the server recovers this leaves the client in a difficult situation. It knows the target server failed, but it does not know if the last message reached its destination ok. If it decides to resend the last message, then that could result in a duplicate message being sent to the address. If each message was an order or a trade then this could result in the order being fulfilled twice or the trade being double booked. This is clearly not a desirable situation.
>
> Sending the message(s) in a transaction does not help out either. If the server or connection fails while the transaction commit is being processed it is also indeterminate whether the transaction was successfully committed or not!
>
> To solve these issues Apache ActiveMQ Artemis provides automatic duplicate messages detection for messages sent to addresses.

See more details about how to configure and use duplicate detection in the [ActiveMQ Artemis documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/duplicate-detection.html).